# expressjs server hangs at random

Tags: node.js, express, httprequest

I am running an express application which uses imagemagick to take a screenshot of a webpage and upload the result to S3 and insert a row into our database.

The service works well however after a few requests eventually the server just hangs upon request. There is no response, but the server is technically not 'down'.

Is there any way for me to see logs, or anything that can be causing this such as memory leak?

Comment: Why do you think it's a memory leak? How are you making those screenshots? Did you determine which part of the request (making the screenshot, uploading to S3, updating the database) is causing the problems?

Answer (score 1):

You should profile your application to check when the bottleneck happens and where it happens in your code. A good starting point is with node's integrated V8 stack profiling module.